# Double type arithmetic operation, weird result in .NET 2.0

Tags: .net, vb.net, double

This is a simple question. I have two double numbers in VB.NET 2.0.

```
A = 226.8
B = 224.4

Dim result As Double = A - B
```

And what I got in result is **2.4000000000000057**

Why is .NET putting there all those zeroes???

Thanks a lot

Comment: .Net loves zeros.  Consider searching for 'Precision'

Comment: See http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx